# Android wearable emulator can't connect with usb connected phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to develop an android wearable application but I don't have wearable device. So I'm using an Android wearable emulator. I tried to connect with wearable emulator and phone. Phone connected with usb cable. My phone API version is 19. Wearable emulator version 20. I installed [Android Wear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app) application in my phone. I tried to connect emulator and device by ADB command.
I'm not sure bluetooth need to open in mobile device because i think usb cable can connect to wearable emulator.

**Check The Device List**

```
adb devices
```

**Results**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
>   List of devices attached
>   HT365W906209    device
>   emulator-5554   device

**AVD communication port to phone**

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

**Results**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>

After executing the above command, I can't connect with my device and emulator. **I followed** [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-wear-part-3-pair-watch-with-device/) **tutorial.**

**This is android wear application in my phone.**
[image]

Comment: Since you didn't mentioned it: You selected `Pair with a new wearable` and `Pair with emulator` right in the Android-Wear Companion app right?

Comment: I want to pair with usb connected phone and wearable emulator.

Comment: That's clear to me. What does your ActionBar in the Companion app say? `Emulator - Connecting...`?

Comment: I want to develop sample notification application. Some of the notification send from phone to wearable device. My main problem is can't connect/pair Phone and wearable emulator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You, and the tutorial as well, haven't mentioned that you explicity selected `Pair with emulator` right inside the Android Wear Companion app. 
So please give this a try:

#### Step 1 - Select "Pair with a new wearable"

[image: pair with a new wearable]

#### Step 2 - Select "Pair with emulator"

[image: pair with emulator]

Afterwards the ActionBar should say **"Emulator - Connecting..."**. Execute the `adb forward` comand once again and it *should* work.