# How to Connect Android Wear running in Emulator to a real Android Device (2016)

Tags: android, wear-os

I know there are some questions on this topic, but most answers are from 2014 and not applicable anymore :(

How do I connect Android Wear running in the Emulator to an Android 6.0 device hanging via USB on the same Machine, with ADB on, on both Instances.
I can see both devices if I do `adb devices`

All the tutorials and answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656619/android-wearable-emulator-cant-connect-with-usb-connected-phone) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524760/not-able-to-connect-android-wear-emulator-with-device)) describe basically to do

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

or

```
adb -s emulator-555X forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

and to start the pairing with the Emulator from a slightly hidden option in the **Android Wear App** - 
**However, I can't find this option in 2016's Android Wear App anymore.**

I'm screwing around with this for two hours, can someone please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have the command-line option right:

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

Then in the Android Wear app on your phone, go to *Pair with a new watch* (under the device dropdown at the upper-left of the main activity); on the *Pair with your watch* screen, you'll find *Pair with emulator* on the overflow (3 dots) menu.

**UPDATE MARCH 2019**

The phone app is now called Wear OS, of course, but the steps are much the same. During the *Add a Watch* process (including during initial setup), *Pair with emulator* should be in the ⋮ overflow menu on the *Connect your Watch* screen.

The ADB command has never changed, and is [documented here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating#pair-phone-with-avd).

Comment: how to do this in 2019?